# Any advantage of Tables over Blobs in Azure when there's no querying?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage

Are there any advantages in using Azure Table Storage over Azure Blob Storage if I don't do any querying? Are performance and cost of Table Storage and Blob Storage similar for this scenario?

For example: users keep notes (short texts) for listed products. In that case key is userID+productID pair, and note body is the value (0 or 1 note for each pair). Some users might have lots of notes for different products and very popular products will have tons of notes by different users.

No need to query all notes neither by user, nor by product. Basically, only operations are getNote(userID, productID), updateNote(userID, productID, etag) and deleteNote(userID, productID, etag).

Comment: You write "I don't do any querying" - and then follow that up by showing the queries you need for working with notes. You're querying.

Comment: @DavidMakogon But it is only referencing by ID. With blobs I can just name blob productID-userID.file

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario  you still need some amount of querying on the data you have. So you will have to go with azure table storage. The table service provides options to handle schema-less data. 
Whereas Azure blob storage is primarily for storing unstructured binary data like files,images, videos etc. if you store each and every record as a blob you will have to access each of them by an unique name like a file name only and it does not really work as querying.

Comment: What querying are you talking about? With blob I can just getNote(userID, productID) = GET $"http: / / blob.storage / {userID}-note-for-{productID}.txt", and similar for delete and update.